# Mail send-receive in Google App Engine (reply_to field)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am reading about mail send/receive in GAE and I have a question about how to use `reply_to` and the form of the email address replied to.

My `register.py` simply writes `message.sender` to database:

```
class User(db.Model):
    userEmail = db.StringProperty()
    userEmailContent = db.StringProperty()

class Register(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, message):        
        newUser = User(userEmail = message.sender)        
        db.put(newUser)

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
  Register.mapping()
], debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

From `incoming.py` I am replying to an applicant's mail with this email:

```
mail.send_mail(sender="<az@example.com>",
               to=message.sender,
               body="reply to this email to register"
               reply_to=/_ah/mail/register@hello-1-world.appspotmail.com)
```

I am imagining that when the applicant replies to this email `register.py` will handle the email and write the applicant's email address to the database. I am not sure how to test this in dev server. Before deploying the app I wanted to ask advice about the correct email address to assign to `reply_to` and if this is the correct way of handling this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `reply_to` address should be a canonical email address without the `/_ah/mail/` prefix  and it follows the same restriction of the `sender` mail address.

> The sender address of a message must be the
>   email address of an administrator for
>   the application, the Google Account
>   email address of the current user who
>   is signed in, or any valid email
>   receiving address for the app.

To test it on your dev server, you could configure [sendmail](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html) and send a mail from your program.
Once received, clicking reply from your mail client should show the reply_to mail address set in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
mail.send_mail(sender="<az@example.com>",
           to=message.sender,
           body="reply to this email to register"
           reply_to="register@hello-1-world.appspotmail.com")
```