# Setting the 'reply to' address using python and google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an email web service based on GAE mail API . How can I set a "reply to" address ?

```
from future import with_statement
```

```
        # read data from request
        mail_to = str(self.request.POST.get('to'))
        mail_from = str(self.request.POST.get('from'))
        mail_subject = str(self.request.POST.get('subject'))
        mail_plain = str(self.request.POST.get('plain'))
        mail_html = str(self.request.POST.get('html'))

        message = mail.EmailMessage()
        message.sender = mail_from
        message.to = mail_to
        message.subject = mail_subject
        message.body = mail_plain
        if mail_html != None and mail_html != "":
            message.html = mail_html

        message.send()
```

Basically I need  to set a different email address to reply to when the client clicks the "reply to" button from his email client .

Comment: isn't `message.sender = mail_from` setting the "from" line on the email, and therefore the "reply-to"?

Comment: @Milimetric a "reply to" email address may be different than the from email address. For example you may send email from example@example.com but you can set the "reply to" as replyxxxx@example.com . If "reply to" is not set I think the email client replies automatically to the "from" email

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mail send-receive in Google App Engine (reply_to field)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271958/mail-send-receive-in-google-app-engine-reply-to-field)

Comment: @Wooble I don't need to receive an email through GAE. I just want to set a "reply to" 'header' so when a client clicks the reply button from his yahoo or whatever email client has the "reply to" email address must appear instead of the "from" email address . I have

Comment: All you have to do is add a "Reply To" header to the message.

Comment: @jathanism unfortunately I don't have much python experience . I use the app more as a web service which I connect to with a php application . I would appreciate if you would submit an answer with a code snippet . Also I'm not sure if GAE supports headers or what kind of headers supports . Here is the gae doc http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/overview.html#Sending_Mail_in_Python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
message.reply_to ='example@googlemail.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
    mail.send_mail(sender = email0,
                   reply_to = email1,
                   to = email2,
                   subject = subject,
                   body = body)
```